# How can I animate a face onto a 3D model using Grease Pencil?

Tags: animation, grease-pencil

Is it possible to animate a 3D model with an animate-able face made with Grease Pencil? I have an idea on how to rig the GP but I'm not sure how I can attach it to my model. I've tried parenting it to my model and then the armature and adding weights but neither worked. Once I pose the head the GP doesn't follow. Fairly new to Blender, so I'm not sure if this sounds absurd or not.